# matplotlib issues when nan first in list

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, nan, figure

I have two lists of numbers which I'm using matplotlib to graph in Python. However if one of the lists begins with the value of nan, matplotlib will not graph any of the 15k+ points I have. However if there is a nan value somewhere in the list after the first value, it simply skips it and graphs the other points fine. I'm curious how to work around this without changing the first nan value.

Comment: You're graphing 15K points and worried about skipping the first one?

Comment: @Gerrat I thinks skipping a NaN here and there is fine, but "matplotlib will not graph any of the 15k+ points I have" is the problem.

Comment: @mgilson:  "...I'm curious how to work around this without changing the first nan value" **...the answer is of course, to just change/drop the first nan value.**

Comment: Current behavior: a list/array containing nan values in any position but the first are plotted correctly, but a nan value in the first position hides the entire series.  Desired behavior: display the valid values in the series even if the first value is a nan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `numpy.isnan` function to mask your list:

```
a=np.array([np.nan,1,2,3,4,np.nan])
mask=~np.isnan(a)
maskedA=a[mask]

#... Plot maskedA here, continue working with a as you normally would.
```

I'm not sure why you want to keep the first nan value -- what do you want matplotlib to do with it other than simply ignore it?  i.e. what do you mean by this statement -- "I'm curious how to work around this without changing the first nan value."

Comment: Ignoring it is fine, and thank you for this solution. I wanted to ignore it without setting it to a value such as 0, 100, etc. which would alter the shape of the figure I was generating.